# FaceBook publishUserAction FaceBook Developer Toolkit 2.0?

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, facebook, facebooktoolkit

I am so lost on this. I am trying to use the publishUserAction feature and have no idea what the correct way is to publish stories on FB. I get an error that I cannot automatically publish one-liners using Connect. OK, so what do I need to do then? Do I need to use the Feed Forms? Any help on this is greatly appreciated. I have been using the FaceBook Developer Toolkit. I can connect to FB just fine and got everything setup there. Just wanted to see if anyone else has been doing this successfully or not with the FBDTK 2.0. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FBDTK 2.0 is quite out of date already due to the the changes facebook have made to their apis. I've moved away from using it in my ASP.NET applications and gone with a pure javascript and manual XFBML approach which works very well with facebook connect and ASP.NET MVC.

You can't publish one line stories using connect at the moment. You need to pop up a feed dialog to allow this (it's not too intrusive though - it works quite well). This video explains it nicely:

http://www.facebook.com/video/video.php?v=636853997423

and you might want to look at the other videos here - very useful:

http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Facebook_Connect_Video_Tutorials

basically though, to publish a feed story via facebook connect you need to do something like this:

```
FB.Connect.showFeedDialog(
  47130247983,
  template_data,
  563683308,
  body_general,
  null,
  FB.RequireConnect.require,
  FB.RequireConnect.promptConnect,
  user_message_prompt,
  user_message);
```

as detailed here:

http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Publishing_Feed_Stories_to_Facebook

Comment: See, that's all I wanted to know. I figured the FBDTK was out of date, but nobody is saying anything. Thanks so much!